# Remove part of variable name for all variables in R

Tags: r, string, variables

I have a dataset in which all of the variable names begin with a string prior to a "." that I would like to batch remove for the whole dataset.For example:

```
frame <- data.frame("sec.xx" = rnorm(10), "sec2.zz" = rnorm(10), "sec3.yy" = rnorm(10))
names(frame)
```

I would like to remove everything in all of the names prior to "." such that the resulting variable names are "xx", "zz", "yy". Thanks for any and all thoughts.

Comment: Use `sub` i.e. `sub('^[^.]*.', '', names(frame))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sub` function.

```
> names(frame) <- sub(".*\\.", "", names(frame))
> names(frame)
[1] "xx" "zz" "yy"
```

Answer (score 2):

The [stringr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package has an str_replace function which will replace values based upon a regular expression. You can use this on the strings to replace everything before and including the first period

```
a = "sec.xx"
a = str_replace(a, ".*\\.", "")
```